# How to search inside an array and return all the searched data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How it is possible to search multipler data inside an array and then display the searched data.

```
struct UserInformationModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var isVip: Bool
    let userIsMale: Bool
    let userName: String
    let age: Int
    let userCountry: String
    let countryIsoCode: String
    let uid: String
    
}
```

And the view model contain the code:

```
class GetUserInformationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allUsers = [UserInformationModel]()

}
```

How to display for example all users inside an array that have the age more than 25.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Filter()` that returns an array containing, in order, the elements of the sequence that satisfy the given predicate.

Usage:

```
  let filteredArray = self.allUsers.filter { age in
      return age.age > 25
    }
```

This will return an array that contain all users that are more than 25 years old.